# Only loop form values that are not blank

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I loop all my items in a form. Some are my form fields are not required. If my value is blank then I don't want it to do anything.

This is what have tried to check for blank values in my for loop:

```
for k, v in cleaned_data.items():
            if v:
                 setattr(myModel, v, CharField())
```

The error I get is: **'' is an invalid keyword argument for this function**

Comment: Could you also add the code for `do something`. Where do you see the error exactly?

Comment: Hi @NCao I have added some code.

Comment: That's never going to work. You can't dynamically add fields to models via setattr. It has to be done in the metaclass.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman won't worry about that 'Model' is actually a class which I then use to add via the meta class, I should have picked a better name for the example above. I'll change it, very confusing sorry. This code works without the if v: part at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add fields to a model using `getattr`, you need to replicate the work done by the `ModelBase` metaclass instead:

```
for k, v in cleaned_data.iteritems():
    if v:
        myModel.add_to_class(v, CharField())
```